# EntityFramework SCOPE_IDENTITY after StoredProcedure insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a bunch of OLD stored procedures that insert values into tables and return nothing.

AND, I can't change the stored procedures as other code still depends on them, etc...

So, after calling an old stored procedure in an EntityFramework 6+ context (with transaction started), how can I get the SCOPE_IDENTITY back (using the EntityFramework context)?

TIA,
Owen

Answer (score 1):

> how can I get the SCOPE_IDENTITY back (using the EntityFramework
>   context)?

You don't need to specifically get it. If your model entity has the `ID` or `Key` property mapped properly with your Table's key column then it will get filled automatically and then you can just get the `ID` property of your model after a insert. You will have to make sure that `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity` property is set for the `Key` column.

Comment: Hmmm. Not really sure what that answer means... I'm calling a STORED PROCEDURE to do the insert and thus don't have an model object to query for the ID. How do I get it (I don't know its ID)...

Comment: Well in that case, consider using ADO.NET instead of Entity Framework.